# interactor issue using Chrome

Tags: xtk

I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.56 (portable version) and  25.0.1364.97 m (installed version) to display some 3D contents. The interation in the 3D scene is not optimal. When I click and move slowly, there is no rotation in the scene. If I move quicker, the interaction starts. It means that I have to interact relatively quickly to mo the 3D scene. This behavior is not seen on firefox 18.0.2.
It looks like there is a minimal movement (or speed movement) under which, the event is thrown away.

The "bug" is worst when the move is in the Y axis of the viewport. Moving in the X axis is better, but not "normal".

Is chrome catching or not propagating some moves to xtk? Is there a threshold for the minimal move or speed?

Thanks,
Laurent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can reproduce if I move the mouse really, really slow..

There is a threshold as defined in here

https://github.com/xtk/X/blob/master/io/interactor.js#L993

The threshold seems reasonable for me. Are you moving really, really slow? We could expose the threshold via a setter.

Comment: No I'm moving just ... normally! The same way as I do in Firefox. The strange thing is that in Firefox, that's ok. It would be usefull to expose the threshold, just in case.

Comment: Cool - can you contribute?

Comment: hehe :-) I'll be very happy to do it... when I'll find some time. I promise! Laurent.

Comment: Ouch! I've just found out that it was because of my mouse frequency! I have a 125hZ/1000Hz; and it is set up at 1000Hz, which causes this kind of bug into Chrome!!

Comment: nice! you could still contribute :)